# Swift, iOS, Seque is not transferring the data I want to pass

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have the following seque. This goes into the ViewImages storyboard.

```
    if  segue.identifier == "ShowImagesSeque", let destination = segue.destination as? ViewImages, let itemIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
        let selectedItem = self.currentItemsArray[itemIndex]

        destination.itemId = selectedItem.itemID

    }
```

Here is the ViewImages class. In the story board, the class is there for the ViewController. When I print out itemId, its `nil`. Why?

```
class ViewImages: UIViewController {
    ... 
    weak var mDelegate:MyProtocol?
    var itemId: String!
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row` equal to `nil` (used if the long `if`)? Use a print statement to check. Also, what is in `currentItemsArray` at this point in time, and what is `itemID` containing? This question doesn't provide enough detail, and this can most likely be debugged by yourself.

Comment: Probably your `if let...` is false. Set a breakpoint, step through and see what is happening.

Comment: Either the segue hasn’t been given that same identifier, the destination is not a `ViewImages` (e.g. is it embedded in navigation controller), or `indexPathForSelectedRow` is `nil`. Check them individually and see which is failing...

Comment: I have buttons on a TableView... when I click that button, i have a seque for it. I think thats the problem since it doesnt know what row its on (since im not clicking the cell). i think i have to put a button in the cell class and then send the indexRow back, trying to figure that out now.