# Perform Seque to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController called ViewImages. Inside of the storyboard, I set up a seque from VC (yellow icon) to ViewImages. I sent the identifier to displayExtraImages and set up the modally properly

Inside of my code, I have this:

```
let destinationVC = ViewImages()
            destinationVC.itemId = self.currentItemsArray[indexPath.row].itemID

            destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayExtraImages", sender: self)
```

Finally, I get the following error:

```
2019-10-06 19:12:40.994388-0400 SoldFor[21403:762477] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<SoldFor.ViewImages: 0x7fc2fff35360>) has no segue with identifier 'displayExtraImages''
```

But I do have the identifier... so im a bit confused. Any help would be great.

Comment: `destinationVC` has no segue it `self` the source of it

Comment: Is this a repost of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58261363/swift-ios-seque-is-not-transferring-the-data-i-want-to-pass)? If that's not needed any more you should delete it.

Comment: @rmaddy kind of, but its a different problem, thats why i made a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options

First

```
let destinationVC = // load the vc from storyboard 
destinationVC.itemId = self.currentItemsArray[indexPath.row].itemID 
self.present(destinationVC,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

Second

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayExtraImages", sender:self.currentItemsArray[indexPath.row].itemID )
```

and implement

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "displayExtraImages"  {
      let  vc = segue.destination as! ViewImages
      vc.itemId  = sender as! Int
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything about that code is wrong:

- It is not the *destination* that holds the segue. It is the *source* — which is probably just `self`. So just tell *yourself* to perform the segue and you'll be fine.
- Do *not* attempt to set `destinationVC.itemId` until we reach `prepare(forSegue:)`.